# how to neatly re-arrange button display on willAnimateRorationToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, uiviewanimation, screen-rotation

I'm teaching myself more iOS by duplicating Apple's calculator app. I've gotten the whole portrait mode working.

Now I want to copy the feature where it resizes the existing buttons, moves them off to the right side, and adds a whole bunch of additional buttons and functionality when the user rotates to landscape.

What I've seen in the docs and online so far has a lot of hardwiring, where I have to write code that manually moves each button to a specific location. I would prefer to go by a ratio of the screen size to support different screens.

So I'd have to resize the buttons and their text, show/hide a set of extra buttons, change the UILabel, show/hide a couple extra UILabels, etc.

can i just have a different xib file with the altered version that it will animate to? or do i have to program the whole thing manually?

what would be the best approach here?

[image: Portrait Calculator]
[image: Landscape Calculator]

Comment: http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/30/orientation-change-tutorial-change-the-view-when-the-orientation-changes/ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is place those buttons within another UIView then rotate the UIView to the new location.
That way it handles all the scaling and positions and will all maintain there position relatively.

Comment: I know this is a really noobish question, but do I just create a whole different .xib file, and stick the buttons into there? what's the transition code look like? is there a way to resize a group of buttons in the interface builder?

Comment: I've never built an app using the interface builder but I'd say so to make sure all the scaling works and stuff. I usually just code stuff in manually.